# Trim everything outside of brackets

Tags: regex, notepad++

How do I do a find and replace in NotePad++ so below lines return just the values in the brackets:

```
This is the first line (39916)
This is the second line (39807)
This is the third line (39783)
```

Returns:

```
39916
39807
39783
```

Comment: `^.*\((\d+)\)$` => `$1`

Comment: Thanks, but how do I use this in NotePad++?

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks very much. If you post as an answer I'll upvote and mark as accepted. :-)

Comment: I'm not going to post it as an answer. You can feel free to post a self-answer with the solution if you wish.

Answer (score 3):

David doesn't want the glory but I'm sure others will be interested in an answer.

Search for:

```
^.*\((\d+)\)$
```

and replace with:

```
$1
```